MAUI iOS - Deploy on older simulator
I recently had to update Xcode from 15.2 to 15.4 in order to use the latest maui-ios workload.
I actually have both installed (thanks Xcodes!).
Xcode 15.2 carried iOS 17.2 as simulator runtime.
Now if I open Xcode 15.4 I still see the simulator running iOS 17.2, but building a simple Maui application fails because it searches for iOS 17.5 (the one carried by Xcode 15.4).
I'm sure installing iOS 17.5 would solve the problem, but I would like not to be forced to do that.
I mean, if I need to test an app on an older version, do I have to install also the right Xcode version?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong.
My machine is running macOS Sonoma 14.7.
This is extracted from the error file:
<key>com.apple.actool.errors</key>
<array>
        <dict>
                <key>description</key>
                <string>The operation couldn’t be completed. Failed to locate any simulator runtime matching options: {
BuildVersionString = 21F77;
Platforms =     (
    "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator"
);
VersionString = "17.5";
}</string>
                <key>failure-reason</key>
                <string>Failed to locate any simulator runtime matching options: {
BuildVersionString = 21F77;
Platforms =     (
    "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator"
);
VersionString = "17.5";
}</string>
        </dict>
</array>


It seems you need to install the latest version and then you can test on older ones.

This reminds me of a funny story. (I can laugh about it now). At some point in time, Between .NET 7 and .NET 8, the building process of my application on my MAC  broke. As it turns out - you had to update your XCODE version, to get it going again. And you know what you had to update also? Your OS version. And can you update it on old MAC machines? No. So if this was your case you could A) publish for Android only. B) buy a new MAC. How frustrated we were I have no words...

Classic Apple. "You're poor? Then you're not suitable to develop for our platforms"
